# How to change the Field Label and format for the formuale field created in the step in dashboard in einstein analytic?

Tags: json, salesforce, dashboard, salesforce-einstein

How to change the Field Label and format for the formuale field created in the step in dashboard in einstein analytic Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Field formatting is controlled via the dataset's XMD. You can modify this JSON file, but the easier way is to use the interface. For created fields, the base dataset (or the first dataset loaded in SAQL) is used for reference the XMD file. Therefore, open that dataset in a new explore window, click on fields in the left panel, and add your created field name as a measure or dimension. Then click the added field and select the formatting.

See more about the [XMD file here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_xmd.meta/bi_dev_guide_xmd/bi_xmd_intro.htm).

See more about [customizing field formatting here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_datasets_customize_display.htm&type=5).